# Wordpress page crashes on load, reload works 100% of time

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, memory, fatal-error

I am getting the error below when I try to load a page.  The page crashes and gives "Critical Error" message, if I reload the page it opens 100% of the time.   I looked for the file but I cannot find it in the specified location.  I did find a file with this name in ./wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/wp-content/object-cache.php, but it does not have a line 329.  I also changed a setting in wp-config.php from define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M'); to define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M');  this change had no affect - do I need to restart something?  Thank you for the help in advance.

[Tue Mar 09 22:42:09.807079 2021] [php7:error] [pid 19671] [client 142.118.122.122:58472] PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 33554440 bytes) in /nas/content/live/COMPANYNAME/wp-content/object-cache.php on line 329, referer: https://www.COMPANYNAME.com/nav-rightway/

Comment: Try to clear your wordpress cache and also increase it more than 512M like 4048M

Comment: How do I clear the cache?  and where do i increase the limit?

Comment: You can increase the php limit from php.ini file and  you can use cache plugin like wp super cache or rocket

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the cache plugin and see if the issue gets resolved and if not then delete the cache plugin from the file manager.

Comment: sorry what do you mean delete the plugin form the file manager.